# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER for distributed transactions

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, distributed-transactions, msdtc

I am trying to set dataflow tasks in a sequence container from SourceDb(exists on my local machine) to TargetDb(exists on azure & can be accessible from SSMS).
I am getting following error whenever I run the package with transaction as Required.

**Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "TargetDb" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.**

It works if I remove the transaction for that container. I have set all the distributed transaction settings correctly. I went through many link on stack overflow but nothing worked for me. Please suggest the solution.

I have also tried this process by restoring both db's on my local machine. It works with transaction successfully. There is nothing wrong with the package.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use transaction in ssis you need to switch on Distributed Transaction coordinator. Another way is to use begin Transaction in execute sql task and in the connection properties set retainsameconnection = True in control flow and all the dft task that needs to be in transaction will follow after this and the last task will be another execute sql task with commit transaction.
Follow the below link to use transaction without switchung on distributed transaction -
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3072/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-transactions-without-msdtc/

Comment: Unfortunately, DTC (which is controlled by the MSDTC service) can't be used on Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Azure cannot participate in transactions with local SQL Servers AFAIK.

> **Limitations**
>      The following limitations currently apply to elastic database transactions in SQL DB:
>
> - Only transactions across databases in SQL DB are supported. Other X/Open 
>     XA resource providers and databases outside of SQL DB cannot
>     participate in elastic database transactions. That means that elastic
>     database transactions cannot stretch across on premises SQL Server and
>     Azure SQL Databases. For distributed transactions on premises,
>     continue to use MSDTC.
> - Only client-coordinated transactions from a .NET application are supported. Server-side support for T-SQL such as BEGIN DISTRIBUTED
>     TRANSACTION is planned, but not yet available.
> - Transactions across WCF services are not supported. For example, you have a WCF service method that executes a transaction. Enclosing
>     the call within a transaction scope will fail as a
>     System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException.

See [this documentation at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview) for a complete discussion of distributed transactions and Azure.